# How to do seek with stdout?

Tags: ruby, stdout

I am trying to implement the Sudoku game in ruby. In that I had a one problem. The problem is I am not able to handle with multiple lines at a time. For example, I have a 5 * 5 boxes. In each boxes the user need to enter the number. For example the user needs to put the number in the second box, I don't know how to go to the second box. Because, the second box is available in the first line. But I was written more than 10 lines.

I was searched in internet. In that they said one way is to use the seek 
method. But the seek method is not working for the stdout.

I did not implemented the Sudoku code. I just tried how to seek the stdout with simple example.

Here is the example code,

```
file = $stdout.dup

file.puts "######### ##########"
file.puts "####################"
file.puts "####################"
file.puts "####################"
file.puts "####################"

file.pos=10
file.puts "#"
```

In this example, The 10th position contains the space, I need to change the space to the #\n. For that I was tried the above code. But it will not work.

Can anyone please explain me why it is not working and how to do this in only ruby not using rails?

Answer (score 0):

Not every filehandle is seekable. If stdout is a disk file, then you can probably seek it, but if stdout is a terminal, then you won't be able to.

Comment: The stdout is a terminal, Is there any  way to do this in terminal ?

Comment: No, you cannot `seek` a terminal. That would mean you would have to time travel, it's simply not possible to skip over something which hasn't even been printed yet.